# Unit test for startup class Configure method .Net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

How to write unit test for below code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
        {        
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                string swaggerJsonBasePath = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c.RoutePrefix) ? "." : "..";
                c.SwaggerEndpoint($"{swaggerJsonBasePath}/swagger/v2/swagger.json", "ResourceDesignService API");
                c.DocExpansion(Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.DocExpansion.None);
                c.EnableFilter("");
                c.EnableTryItOutByDefault();
            });

            logger.LogInformation("Configure called.");
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                context.Request.Scheme = "https";
                return next();
            });

            app.UseRequestBodyLogging();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {                
                app.UseResponseBodyLogging();
            }

            app.UseForwardedHeaders();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
```

I am calling this method from my test method like this:

```
[TestMethod]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(NullReferenceException))]
        public void ConfigureTest()
        {
            Mock<IConfiguration> mockIconfig = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
            Mock<IApplicationBuilder> mockAppBuilder = new Mock<IApplicationBuilder>();
            Mock<IWebHostEnvironment> mockIenv = new Mock<IWebHostEnvironment>();
            var mockLoger = new Mock<ILogger<Startup>>();

                Startup startup = new Startup(mockIconfig.Object, mockIenv.Object);
                startup.Configure(mockAppBuilder.Object, mockIenv.Object, mockLoger.Object);
                Assert.IsNotNull(startup);
        }
```

Test method is calling startup.Configure method, but getting exception from first line of method app.UseSwagger(); System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')'
not able to understand how to mock this

Comment: Your only using empty mock objects, so when you call Configure it tries to call app.UseSwagger() and it throws System.ArgumentNullException() because you've not configured your mock object to handle that. If you want it to, you need to tell it how.